# Back up in documentdb

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to take a snapshot of my current collection and then restore it at any point of time later in documentdb. Available options are using azure migration tool. Is it possible to do this by calling API through my application built in node?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `Read Document Feed` API to scan the documents within a collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-documents The API supports "change feed" for incremental retrieval of documents from the collection. The method in Node.js is `readDocuments`.

Aside from this, the DocumentDB team has announced that self-service backup will be available, which will have its own API. You can find the status of the feature at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6331712-backup-solution-for-documentdb